# How to Solve Retrieval Challenges in an Information Retrieval Application with Long HTML Pages Using LangChain, OpenAI, and FAISS?

Tags: langchain, py-langchain, llama-index

I am currently developing an information retrieval application designed to work with HTML pages, ranging in length from 5 to 200 pages. The application utilizes LangChain, OpenAI, and FAISS for its core functionalities. A significant part of the process involves chunking HTML pages, many of which contain numerous tables. My method involves extracting tables from the HTML pages, identifying them by their top titles for indexing and retrieval purposes.

However, I have encountered two main issues during retrieval:

- Long Query Handling: When the query is slightly longer, the retrieval system does not return the correct answer. It seems to struggle with maintaining accuracy as the query length increases.
- Variance in Wording: The system fails to correctly retrieve chunks when there is a discrepancy between the wording in the query and the chunks. For example, if the query uses "six" but the chunk contains "6", the system does not recognize them as a match.

These challenges are hindering the application's ability to accurately retrieve information, especially when dealing with nuanced or detailed queries.

I am reaching out to this community for advice or strategies on how to address these issues. Specifically, I am interested in approaches that could improve the handling of long queries and the recognition of synonymous terms or different word forms (like numerals versus written numbers) during the retrieval process.

Any suggestions or insights on how to refine the retrieval accuracy of this application would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!